# Installations going to folder with less space

Tags: partitioning, software-installation, home-directory, storage

Whenever I install any software, it goes to shlok-Lenovo-Legion-Y530-15ICH and soon the free memory becomes so low that I cancel installation.
[image: Storage Screenshot]

However when I check the storage of my home directory from Files Properties, it shows over 73GB free memory:
[image: Properties]

So I tried to install softwares in home\documents but still shlok-Lenovo-Legion-Y530-15ICH is used up.

How can I utilize the free space and install softwares at my desired directory?

Comment: You have made your root partition too small (8 GB) and softwares would get installed in your root partition.

Comment: How can I increase size of root partition